# Reverse string without affecting specific characters that user can input

Tags: java, string, reverse

Need to reverse string without affecting all non alphabetical charachters and specific characters that user can input to ignore. I figured out how to ignore non alphabetical characters and it do the job when text-to-reverse match text-to-ignore strings but don't work when it different.
Here's my code:

```
public class Anagram {

public static String reverseString(String rev, String ignore) {
    char[] str = rev.toCharArray();
    int r = str.length - 1;
    int l = 0;
    if ((ignore != null) && ignore.contains(rev)) {
        char[] ign = ignore.toCharArray();
        while (l < r)
            for (int i = 0; i < ignore.length(); i++) {
                if (!Character.isAlphabetic(str[l]) || (ign[i] == str[l])) {
                    l++;
                } else if (!Character.isAlphabetic(str[r]) || (ign[i] == str[r])) {
                    r--;
                } else {
                    char tmp = str[l];
                    str[l] = str[r];
                    str[r] = tmp;
                    l++;
                    r--;
                }
            }
    } else {
        while (l < r) {
            if (!Character.isAlphabetic(str[l])) {
                l++;
            } else if (!Character.isAlphabetic(str[r])) {
                r--;
            } else {
                char tmp = str[l];
                str[l] = str[r];
                str[r] = tmp;
                l++;
                r--;
            }
        }
    }
    return new String(str);
}}}
```

**Example what i need:
Input: String rev "abcdefg", String ignore "cf"
Output: "gecdbfa"**

Comment: Please provide example inputs and outputs.

Comment: Example what i need: Input: String rev "abcdefg", String ignore "cf" Output: "gecdbfa"

Comment: And how do you suggest to do this - in your own words? And what is wrong with your current code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, when you swap values at 2 positions, they both have to be valid characters, meaning, both alphabetic and not of the characters of `ignore`. Second issue is you are equating a character of `ignore` directly with left pointer of the `rev` string in `ign[i] == str[l]`. They need not coincide index-wise this way.

---

**Algorithm:**

- Create a set of all the characters in `ignore`.
- Create a `result` array of type `char` with length same as `rev`.
- Create another `reserved` boolean array with length same as `rev`.
- Now, loop on `rev` char by char. If it is non-alphabetic or one of the chars of `ignore`, fix that position with that char. In `reserved`, mark this index as `true` as we can't mess with this index now.
- Once done, move again on the string `rev` from left to right and this time only consider alphabetic chars and the ones which aren't a part of `ignore`. Now, add them in a reverse way inside `result` to actually store in the *reversed* state. Note that the next non-reserved location won't always be sequential in nature with a simple `ptr--`. We would need a while loop inside to get the next non reserved seat and insert them there.

**Snippet:**

```
public static String reverseString(String rev, String ignore) {
  Set<Character> set = new HashSet<>();
  for(int i = 0; i < ignore.length(); ++i){
    set.add(ignore.charAt(i));
  }
  
  char[] result = new char[rev.length()];
  boolean[] reserved = new boolean[rev.length()];
  
  
  for(int i = 0; i < rev.length(); ++i){
    if(!Character.isAlphabetic(rev.charAt(i)) || set.contains(rev.charAt(i))){
      result[i] = rev.charAt(i);
      reserved[i] = true;
    }
  }
  
  int ptr = rev.length() - 1;
  for(int i = 0; i < rev.length(); ++i){
    if(Character.isAlphabetic(rev.charAt(i)) && !set.contains(rev.charAt(i))){
      while(ptr >= 0 && reserved[ptr]) ptr--;
      result[ptr--] = rev.charAt(i);
    }
  }
  
  return new String(result);
}
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onecompiler.com/java/3ya647bwe)